# Javascript function not defined, possible namespace issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, namespaces

And I don't understand why. I'm suspecting it is a namespace issue but the function and its calls are defined within the same doc ready function.

When I try to call the function in the console I get **calcPCs is not defined**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function calcPCs(id) {

        var si = $(id).find(".Screened-In").text();
        var so = $(id).find(".Screened-Out").text();

        var ref = $(id).find(".Referred").text();
        var ret = $(id).find(".Retained").text();

        $(id).find(".Screened-In").append(' (' + Math.floor((+si / (+si + +so)) * 100) + '%)');
        $(id).find(".Screened-Out").append(' (' + Math.floor((+so / (+si + +so)) * 100) + '%)');

        $(id).find(".Referred").append(' (' + Math.floor((+ref / (+ref + +ret)) * 100) + '%)');
        $(id).find(".Retained").append(' (' + Math.floor((+ret / (+ref + +ret)) * 100) + '%)');
    };            

    calcPCs("#northwest");
    calcPCs("#northeast");
    calcPCs("#west");
    calcPCs("#east");
    calcPCs("#central");
    calcPCs("#gtr");
});
```

Comment: Post the exact error.

Comment: Sorry was just editing my post to include. 'calcPCs is not defined'

Comment: Including the stack trace would help, as the error doesn't seem to be in the code you've provided. You must be trying to use `calcPCs` somewhere else.

Comment: Are you calling calcPCs elsewhere?

Comment: It might be undefined in functions you call outside the document.ready. I would not have a function inside it myself since it will not be available outside the ready

Comment: @mplungjan if I move it outside, same result

Comment: This is a scoping issue. There are many duplicates to this question.

Comment: @zzzzBov may we have one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `calcPCs` from the console. Any code you type in the console is executed in the global namespace, but `calcPCs` was defined inside the anonymous function you passed to `.ready()`, and thus counts as a local variable of that function. Local variables are not available from outside the function body.

Comment: An additional note.  You *can* execute the method from the console, provided you set a break point inside the scope where the method is available.  Once the breakpoint is hit, and while it is paused, you can run the method from the console.